# Nested lambda expressions results in a warning in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I've installed Eclipse Luna on my MAC OSX with Java8 and when I write simple nested Lambda expression it give the following warning:

```
(Recovered) Internal inconsistency detected during lambda shape 
 analysis
```

Eventually, the code compiles and run perfectly, but still this warning is disturbing....

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code that gives the error. Also, what version of Luna are you using?

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432110

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800