# Lambda expression results in warning in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda

I have a very similar problem as described in this unanswered question:
[Nested lambda expressions results in a warning in Eclipse Luna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579881/nested-lambda-expressions-results-in-a-warning-in-eclipse-luna)

I am using Eclipse Luna (Service Release 1, 4.4.1) with Windows 7 and Java 8 (jdk 1.8.0_05). The following (**edited**) code:

```
Collections.sort(new LinkedList<>(), (c1, c2) -> {
    return c1.equals(c2)? 1 : 0;
});
```

yields in a warning:

```
(Recovered) Internal inconsistency detected during lambda shape analysis
```

The warning is assigned to this part of the code: "(c1, c2) ->".

**Note**: interestingly, the shorter version omitting the return statement compiles fine without any warnings:

```
Collections.sort(new LinkedList<>(), (c1, c2) -> c1.equals(c2)? 1 : 0);
```

The same is true for this code where the types of c1 and c2 are given explicitly

```
Collections.sort(new LinkedList<>(), (Object c1, Object c2) -> {
    return c1.equals(c2)? 1 : 0;
});
```

What is going on here? (I don't believe that this bug suggestion: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432110 (given in a comment of the related question) is of any help as there the warning occurrs in the context of an error.)

**EDIT:** The above code is a MWE, the original code that caused the problem looks like this:

```
    Collections.sort(list, (c1, c2) -> {
        Method m1 = this.allMethods.get(c1);
        Method m2 = this.allMethods.get(c2);

        int c = new Integer(m1.getParameterCount()).compareTo(
                new Integer(m2.getParameterCount()));

        if (c == 0) {
            Integer i1 = 0;
            Integer i2 = 0;
            if (ConstructorFactory.isTypeAcceptable(m1.getReturnType())) {
                i1 = 1;
            }
            if (ConstructorFactory.isTypeAcceptable(m2.getReturnType())) {
                i2 = 1;
            }

            c = i1.compareTo(i2);
        }

        if (c == 0) {
            c = m1.getName().compareTo(m2.getName());
        }

        return c;
    });
```

**EDIT 2:** Eclipse Kepler did NOT show this warning (same Java version).

Comment: Btw. the given code is intended to be a MWE - it does nothing meaningful.

Comment: This code : `Collections.sort(list, (c1, c2) -> {return c1.equals(c2)? 1 : 0;});` also shows the warning.

Comment: Nice, this is close to a true MWE :-) I will update my question - it doesn't make sense to use a more complicated example.

Comment: However, this shortcut version of your code works fine:
Collections.sort(new LinkedList<>(), (c1, c2) -> c1.equals(c2)? 1 : 0); -- Strange...

Comment: it also gives no warning with `(Object a, Object b)` (We may want to find something cleaner, though)