# Internal inconsistency detected during lambda shape analysis

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

In a similar problem as is described in [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579881/nested-lambda-expressions-results-in-a-warning-in-eclipse-luna) and [this other unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995124/lambda-expression-results-in-warning-in-eclipse-luna), I receive a warning in Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) (20140925-1800) reading, "(Recovered) Internal inconsistency detected during lambda shape analysis". The code is as follows:

```
public static <T> T findFirst(Iterable<T> list, Predicate<T> condition)  {
    /* ... */
}

public static Integer findFirstPrime(Iterable<Integer> integers) {
    return findFirst(integers,
            integer -> {
                /* return either true or false */
            }
    );
}
```

The warning is raised on the text reading `integer ->`. There is a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432110) stating that the issue is fixed for Eclipse Mars 4.5, but what can I do in the meantime? If I want to use `@SuppressWarnings`, how do I know what warning type to supply?

Comment: Often you can get rid of these warnings just with a little hand holding to ease the burden on the type inference implementation, e.g. something like `(Integer integer) -> ...` to make sure it knows what it's doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not the type of warning you can suppress.

At least it looks like the fix has been back-ported to the 4.4.2 maintenance release of Luna, which is due to be released on February 27, 2015:

https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse/releases/4.4.2/plan